# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - 1 million record - Double quotes get appended to each

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have a TXT file that inserts data in a Mysql table using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. The problem is it adds double quotes in each column as it is like the TXT file. There are 1 million records in total.

This is my SQL Query

```
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ' Base.txt' INTO TABLE temp_data CHARACTER 
SET
   latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

So 1 million records are inserted in the table but with `double quotes` appended to each record. Example below.

```
"100+ 100B  BATTERY"    "19.87" "28"    "Replacement Battery"   "NEW"   "CS-BDV510SL-1.jpg" "MOBILE DEVICES / CELL PHONES BATTERIES"    "2" "100+"  "100B  BATTERY" "HRVH-8"    "3.80"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
```

I tried using the `ENCLOSED BY '"'`, which removes the double-quotes. But then it dumps only half of the records. Here is the query that dumps ONLY  half the records?

```
SET
   NAMES latin1;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Base.txt' INTO TABLE temp_data CHARACTER 
SET
   latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

CSV

```
"100+ 100B  BATTERY"    "19.87" "28"    " Replacement Battery"  "NEW"   "CS-BDV510SL-1.jpg" "MOBILE DEVICES / CELL PHONES BATTERIES"    "2" "100+"  "100B  BATTERY" "AX-HRVH-8" "3.80"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"100+ V5  BATTERY"  "19.87" "28"    "5 Battery Replacement Battery" "NEW"   "_CS-BDV510SL-1.jpg"    "MOBILE DEVICES / CELL PHONES BATTERIES"    "2" "100+"  "V5  BATTERY"   "AX-6D6T-5" "3.80"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"100+ V5100B  BATTERY"  "19.87" "28"    "V5100B Battery Replacement Battery"    "NEW"   "S-BDV510SL-1.jpg"  "MOBILE DEVICES / CELL PHONES BATTERIES"    "2" "100+"  "V5100B  BATTERY"   "AX-6D6U-0" "3.80"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
```

Create table statement

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_data` (
  `keywords` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `fixedprice` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `condition` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `image1url` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `merchantcategory` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `leadtime` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Manufacturer` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Model_Number` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `AZ_Code` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `Volts` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Watts` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `ColorTemp` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Shape` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Life` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Base` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Try `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY`

Comment: Make sure you have the line terminator correct, it might be `\r\n`

Comment: show some rows of the csv and the create table, i never heard that mysql would add double quotes

Comment: @Barmar I tried, but its not working

Comment: Look at the file with a hex editor to make sure you know what the line endings are.

Comment: @nbk updated the question with rows of the CSV and with the create table statement –

Comment: we can't see in the question which ending every row has, it can be \n or \r\n, this is like @Barmar already told you doable with a hexeditor

Comment: @barmar The person who wrote the script said it ends with CarriageReturn: ASCII 13

Comment: That's `\r`, not `\n`.

Comment: @Barmar I will try that

Comment: @Barmar that worked but the first column "keywords"  now has the double quotes in it , rest all column looks good, I have updated the latest SQL with \r in the question

Comment: I  suspect it's actually `\r\n` line endings. So now the `\n` is being treated as the first character of the first column, which prevents the `"` from being used as the enclosure. Is there some reason you refuse to examine the file with a hex editor? Do you know what that is?

Comment: @Barmar Looks like you are right - using https://hexed.it/ (a handy online hex editor) I'm seeing an 0D and 0A couplet between lines.

Comment: `0d = \r 0a = \n`